# Cannot install grub for dual boot ubuntu 13.10 and windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

My pc already has windows 7 and I installed ubuntu on a different partition because during the installation of ubuntu i was not getting the option "To install ubuntu side-by-side". Therefore, I installed it on a different partition and the installation was successful.

Anyways, after installing ubuntu, I do not get the boot option as It directly boots me into the windows 7 OS.

I googled the problem and it seemed that I had to use the ubuntu live cd and install boot-repair, therefore, I installed boot-repair on and when I run the recommended-repair option I get the message "Please enable a repository containing the [grub2] packages in the software sources of Ubuntu 13.10 (sda6). Then try again."

I am also attaching the link for boot summary information

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6565132/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After boot-repair what was the options in grub menu list?Did you try `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` command on terminal?

Comment: When I try to run grub-install /dev/sda it says : Path `/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting.

Comment: install gparted and upload its screenshot.

Comment: I dont see any upload button, how can i upload the screenshot?

Comment: upload the screenshot to imgur.com and post the link here.

Comment: did you change the UEFI mode to legacy mode in bios?

Comment: No I did not, should I check and change it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,change the *UEFI mode* to *Legacy mode* in bios.Because UEFI mode makes the windows to boot directly and block Ubuntu from booting.

After that make sure that you boot from the HDD.

Comment: I have disabled EFI boot sources from the BIOS. But still I dont get the dual boot option and it loads directly into windows. This can be seen from the following link http://imgur.com/Zb7S3Ez

Comment: change to legacy boot sources and then ran [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: I can only enable/disable Boot sources. Therefore, I have disabled EFI boot source and now I will run boot-repair from ubuntuLiveCD

Comment: After running boot-repair im getting a message "Please enable a repository containing the [grub2] packages in the software sources of Ubuntu 13.10 (sda6). Then try again."

Comment: after clicking on the recommended repair option does the system displays ` "Please enable a repository containing the [grub2] ` error.

Comment: update the repositories by running `sudo apt-get update` and then try boot-repair.

Comment: during the update , it gets hang at waiting to receive headers.

Comment: I am thinking of deleting all the partitions by using gparted and then install both windows and ubuntu. I have backed up my data. Any advice?

Comment: No,continue if there any problem occurs post it to me.

Comment: Ok Thank you. I have tried to update it again but it stucks at [waiting to receive headers] . One error that I see when I boot the system before loading to windows, and the error is as follows:
"Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi":14
error: variable root isnt set

Comment: After successful update followed by boot-repair, it still gives the error  "Please enable a repository containing the [grub2] packages in the software sources of Ubuntu 13.10 (sda6). Then try again."